# Solve the non-square matrix to get the closest unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, unitary-matrices

First, I would like to say that I have asked similar question to this before, but I noticed that many details are missing so I decided to rewrite the question with clear details.

I have a real matrix $D$ with size $m$ x $n$ , and $n < m$ such that $D'D = I_n$, where $D'$ denoted the transpose of the matrix $D$.  I need to get the real matrix $V$ with size $n$ x $m$ such that $DV = Y$ where the matrix $Y$ has $Y'Y = I_m$ (It means get the matrix $V$ which make $(DV)'*(DV) = I_m)$.   Does it exist?  In other words it's to get the closest unitary matrix $Y$ by non-square matrix $V$.

In case if the matrix $V$ is square, I think the solution can be straightforward, but what's about it's not square? let's take an example that $m$=6  and $n$=4.

Comment: Hey, the $m<n,$ makes $D'D=I_n,$ impossible because of rank equality you may see partial isometries where $DD'=I_m$ for $m\times n$ matrix $D$.

Comment: I am really sorry for that mistake, I corrected the question now.  it's $n<m$

Comment: If $D'D=I_n$ and $DV=Y$, then $Y'Y = V'D'DV=V'V$. But $V'V$ has the same rank as $V$ which has rank $\le n < m$, so $V'V \ne I_m$.

Comment: @angryavian I got it. Thank you. Ok, is it possible to get the closest unitary matrix $Y$ ? it means it's not important that $Y′Y=I_m$ but close to $I_m$. Is there a way to get that ?